# recursion big o with log n

Tags: algorithm, performance

What would be the Big O of this function:

```
def foo(n):
    if (n <= 1):
        return 0
    else:
        return n + foo(n/2) + foo(n/2)
```

I think it might O(2^logn) because in each call, there are two other calls and n is divided by 2 until it gets to 1, thus the logn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is *O(2<sup>logn</sup>)*, which really is equivalent to *O(n)*.

You can analyse it as follows:

T(n) = 1 + 2T(n/2)
        = 1 + 2(1 + 2T(n/4)) = (2²-1) + 2²T(n/4)
        = (2²-1) + 2²(1 + 2T(n/8)) = (2³-1) + 2³T(n/8)
        ...
        = (2<sup>logn</sup> - 1) + 2<sup>logn</sup>
        = (n-1) + 2n
        = O(n)

This may be a surprising result, but a snippet measuring the fraction between *n* and the number of calls of `foo`, illustrates this time complexity:

```js
let counter;

function foo(n) {
    counter++;
    if (n <= 1)
        return 0;
    else
        return n + foo(n/2) + foo(n/2);
}

for (let n = 1; n < 100000; n*=2) {
    counter = 0;
    foo(n);
    console.log(counter/n);
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling that it is O(log n) because the time spent at each `n` is really constant because it is just a sum. When I start at n = 1, it is a constant, for n = 2 it is a constant as well because the result is 2 + foo(1) + foo(1) which is constant operation. It is not like we are traversing a list. So we have log(n) constants which add upto O(log n). What am I missing here?

Comment: You are missing the fact that the recursion happens twice, and so the immediate "children" are visited 2 times, and the grandchildren are each visited 4 times, ...etc. This exponential number of visits compensates for the otherwise logarithmic "divide-and-conquer".

Comment: ah , the n/2 portion is visited twice - yes it would result in two children at each node in the tree. It would have been log n if I stored the intermediate result in a variable say x and then compute the result as n + 2x

Comment: Indeed, memoization would change the time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Moreover, you can use the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)) as well (the first case). In your case as the recursive relation is `T(n) = 2T(n/2) + 1`, if we want to write the relation in the form of `T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)`, we will have:

```
a = 2, b = 2, f(n) = 1
=> c_crit = log2(2) = 1
```

As `f(n) = 1 = O(n^c)` for all `c > 0`, we can find a `0 < c < 1` that `c < c_crit = 1`. Hence, the first case of the master theorem is satisfied. Therefore, `T(n) = \Theta(n)`.